# Eclipse - Can't change background color after I applied a theme

Tags: eclipse

I've applied the theme Moonrise to Eclipse Luna, now I'm trying to change the background color to the window where I write my code.
To do so I go to "Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editor -> Text Editors -> Appearence Color Options", there I select "Background color" and set the one I want.
By clicking on "Apply", the color is set and I can see it, but as soon as I close the Preferences window, the color goes back to gray as set by the theme.
How should I do to make the change permanent?
If that wasn't possible, how do I reset to default? I pushed the "Restore defaults" button, but as I close the window, it goes back to the theme colors. I've also deleted eclipse folder and put a new one, everything is back to default but the background color. Does eclipse saves any settings around the system? I use Windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the theme's CSS had to be edited to perform this.

- Close eclipse and locate the plugin's jar at `/[eclipseDirectory]/plugins/com.github.eclipseuitheme.themes.moonrise-ui_[version].jar`
- Open the jar and navigate to the applicable `moonrise-ui.css` for the within `/themes/css/`
- Search for `#202020` and replace with the color code you'd like

If you find the color is not applied, check that you made the change in the  `moonrise-ui[platform].css` which applies to your platform (Win/Linux) or the theme you selected (Moonrise / Moonrise standalone).